# Script in include path not accessible to home user

Tags: linux, permissions

So I have put a shortcut to one my scripts into /usr/bin so it is included. But command can be run only by root, other users failed to run it :(

```
$ sudo su
# chmod +x /opt/altf2/altf2
# ln -s /opt/altf2/altf2 /usr/bin/altf2
# altf2
It's working
# chmod 777 /opt/altf2/altf2
# chmod 777 /usr/bin/altf2
# su francois
$ altf2 gedit
altf2: command not found
$ /usr/bin/altf2
bash: /usr/bin/altf2: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the `francois` user cannot step into the `/opt/altf2` directory. You shoud add at least `r` permssion on it. It will not allow listing, but will allow accessing of explicitly specified files.

Comment: `chmod -R +r /opt/altf2` not doing anything :(

Comment: also tried `chmod a+r /opt/altf2`

Comment: What about the permissions of /opt?

Comment: `chmod -R a+r /opt` not working :(

Comment: The user needs execute rights for every directory involved: `chmod a+rx /opt; chmod a+rx /opt/altf2`